# How to suspend all scripts until button is clicked?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a start game screen and whenever you click the start game button, you can play. How would I make it so all the scripts would suspend until I click that button?

I dont currently have any code or any start screen I'm just wonderinh

Comment: you can start with the scripts disabled and use script.enabled=true to start its execution

Answer (score 0):

I think another way of doing it would be to only instantiate whatever elements compose your game when you click on that button (Spawn the level, player, etc) or if you need them to be on screen before have some sort of "StartGame" function in the scripts that enables their usual behavior when you click on the button. Or a combination of both.

That may prove useful later if you intend to have functionalities to pause or restart the game to control your objects more precisely than shutting down all scripts.